# Is there an alternative to using multiple inheritance in python in my case?

Tags: python, inheritance, design-patterns, django-rest-framework, multiple-inheritance

Let's say there are several classes

```
class Order:
  def create_basic_order(self):
    pass
    # something here

  def create_difficult_order(self):
    pass
    # something here  


class Point:
  def create_full_point(self):
    pass
    # something here

  def create_limited_point(self):
    pass
    # something here
```

And the client sends a request with a specific command in json format. For example `{"command": "create_limited_point"}`.

And the server should execute the appropriate command. In this case: `Point().create_limited_point()`.

All commands are different.
The most obvious way to do it without the '`if` construct' is like this:

```
class App(Order, Point):
  pass
  # maybe something here

# Code to handle client request
command = 'create_limited_point'
a = App()
method_to_call = getattr(a, command)
method_to_call()
```

The class App collects all the methods that the client can use.
Is this a good way to accomplish the task at hand?

Comment: Can you provide some more information? It is really hard to say what is appropriate when the example literally does nothing. You could go for composition over inheritance and search through the components. You could go for a mapping from name to callable and skip having a class structure at all. You could go for a similar mapping but auto-create it using ``dir`` on all classes. You could use decorators to register each command. You could...

Comment: @MisterMiyagi the main question is that i need to execute the command sent by the client. This could be done by placing methods (commands) in one class and calling it by name. But then this class can grow with the growth of commands that the client wants to execute. To do this, i can just split the class into logical subclasses. But then how to understand from which class i need to call the client method?

Comment: More information needed to give a good answer, especially about your classes. Do they only exist as a collection for the commands or would they be discrete classes, even without the commands?

Comment: The idea is that the user gives a command and this command must be executed. The commands themselves can be divided logically. For example, some commands refer to an Order, some to a Point. Therefore, the question is how to decompose it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your app is but you are right, the solution you suggest is terrible. And if you can, you should probably refactor this code a bit. Multiple inheritance is usually a bad idea.

Something like that might work better for you.

```
import abc
from typing import Dict


class EventHandler(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def handle(self):
        pass


class BasicOrderHandler(EventHandler):
    def handle(self):
        pass


class DifficultOrderHandler(EventHandler):
    def handle(self):
        pass


class FullPointHandler(EventHandler):
    def handle(self):
        pass


class LimitedPointHandler(EventHandler):
    def handle(self):
        pass


class App:
    commands_handlers_mapper: Dict[str, EventHandler] = {
        'create_limited_point': LimitedPointHandler,
        'create_full_point': FullPointHandler,
        'create_difficult_order': BasicOrderHandler,
        'create_basic_order': BasicOrderHandler
    }

    def execute_command(self, command: str) -> None:
        handler = self.commands_handlers_mapper[command]
        handler.handle()


command = 'create_limited_point'
a = App()
a.execute_command(command)
```

Bonus points for putting those `commands` into constants, which is just a class attribute, enums or just string assigned to a variable.

Comment: What is the purpose of the intermediate classes? Why not just store functions/callables?

Comment: To have and use an interface.

Comment: That interface is just a call. It doesn't actually contain any information that "a callable" does not already express.

Comment: Until you need more code there, yes. It's obvious you'd achieve the same thing in this simple example using functions. OP wanted to start with OOP from the beginning. So that's that.

Comment: It turns out that for each command i need to create its own class, even if there can be many of these commands? funny :)

Answer (score 1):

Since `App` is used just as a namespace, there is no need for the complexity of multiple inheritance. It is easier and more flexible to just go for an explicit namespace of callables.

```py
order = Order()

def hello():
    return 'Hello!'

commands = {
    # arbitrary callable
    'hello': hello,
    # methods of shared object
    'create_basic_order': order.create_basic_order,
    'create_difficult_order': order.create_difficult_order,
    # methods of individual objects
    'create_full_point': Point().create_full_point,
    'create_limited_point': Point().create_limited_point
}

# execute command by name
command = 'create_limited_point'
commands[command]()
```

Of course, one can automatise various parts of this as desired.

```py
# automatically use name of callable as command name
commands = {
    call.__name__: call
    for call in (
        hello,
        Point().create_full_point, Point().create_limited_point,
    )
}
# add all public methods of an object
for name in dir(order):
    if name.startswith('_'): continue
    commands[name] = getattr(order, name)
```